# rendering custom form in default theme

Tags: layout

I have a custom form which I have made and want to  display within the magento default theme (for now, until create specific css for it). To do this I have set out to try and understand magento's layouts, I've read [this](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/) and [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts) as well as a couple of other pages to try and learn the basics before I dive in, but the articles seems really unhelpful (or am I missing some nuggets of quality information?). So I had a look around at the layout files that come with magento to try and learn from them, the goal being, work out what handles I need to use. IVE FAILED, hence this question.

How do I add my form in to a Magento theme?

indexController.php

```
$this->loadLayout('handle_name')->renderLayout();
```

module/modulename.xml

```
<handle_form>
    <block type="core/template" name="the_form" output="toHtml" template="ps/prefcentre/signup.phtml" />
</handle_form>
```

I realise the above will only render the form but how do I create this file to render a default layout around it.

Ive tried so many different options i've lost track of what ive done. From what I have read I first assumed that the default tags held within other .xml files would cause the basic template to load.

I know once I have got this I will be able to learn how to use the layouts, I'm so stuck on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action should look like this:

```
$this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
```

Let's assume your module is called `modulename`, your controller `IndexController` and the action `indexAction`. In this case your layout file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <firstmodule_index_layout>
        <reference name="content"><!-- this means you add a block to the content-->
            <block type="core/template" name="the_form" as="the_form" template="ps/prefcentre/signup.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </firstmodule_index_layout>
</layout>
```

Basically, each action has it's own layout handled built like this:
`<module_controller_action>`

Comment: That makes sense as to why each of the handles are named in the way they are. I have followed your advice, which has rendered a default template as expected, but my form is not being shown, can you offer any other options as to why it may be not working?

Comment: @tony09uk. Do you see any errors in var/log? Also make sure your layout handle name matches the action name

Comment: in var/log/layout.log - 2013-07-11T09:24:45+00:00 INFO (6): firstmodule_index_layout
in var/log/system.log - 2013-07-23T07:46:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 10: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name  in /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

Comment: this means the layout file is wrongly formatted. Make sure you closed the right tags. I've edited the answer with how the full file should look. I assumed you module name is `firstmodule`, the controller name is `index` and the action name is `layout` based on the error message.

Comment: Thankyou, in making the changes, i left the / off the closing tag. 
And thanks for teaching me where to find the error logs, that will be very useful for all my layout problems